# What's the difference between these two javascript calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the 'function' do in the following?

```
$('.event-row').on('mouseover',function(){
  arc.event_handler.event_row_over();
  });

$('.event-row').on('mouseover',arc.event_handler.event_row_over );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very important difference.

- The first one will call the function with <strike>the context</strike> its `this` value as the `event_handler` object.
- The second one will call the function with <strike>the context</strike> its `this` value as the DOM element to which the handler is bound.

So the first one preserves the expected <strike>calling context</strike> `this` value, which may be required by the function.

Comment: ok, this is making more sense as this is what we saw experimentally.

Comment: @timpone: Yeah, people trip on this quite a bit. They expect that the function will keep its relationship to the object, when in fact once you detach it from the object, it has no memory of where it came from.

Comment: Another difference is that the first way calls whatever function `arc.event_handler.event_row_over` references at the time the event occurs, while the second way will call whatever function `arc.event_handler.event_row_over` references at the time the `.on()` statement is executed - not necessarily the same function. Note also that the second one allows `arc.event_handler.event_row_over()` to return a value back to jQuery (which in the case of a mouseover handler doesn't mean much, but in a click handler the return value might cancel the default behaviour).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Hmmm... Not sure what you mean by calling it at the time the `on()` is executed. It looks to me like the function is being passed, not called. Did I misunderstand your comment? EDIT: Oh, I see what you mean. The function may be replaced later on, but before the event occurs. Good point.

Comment: The "context" you refer to is the function's `this` value, and **`this` is not context**. The term "context" in ECMAScript is used in various ways, primarily for *exectution context*. It is **never** use to refer to a function's `this` value.

Comment: thx, Rob - would you add .call(this) at the end to pass this to the called method? I use this but it's a little bit of black magic to me honestly.

Comment: @timpone—it depends on what value you want `this` to have. Sometimes it's irrelevant, sometimes it isn't. Perhaps just as important is that in the second example, the first argument passed to `event_row_over` will be the related event object. Not so in the first.

Comment: @timpone—the second case is more or less equivalent to `arc.event_handler.event_row_over.call(theDOMElement, event)` where *theDOMElement* is the element that the listener is on (referred to in HTML5 as the "context node", but please don't confuse that with ECMAScript context. The term "context" is used much more generally in HTML5).

Answer (score 3):

In the first case with the anonymous function `this` inside that function is bound to the DOM element that caused the event. This is a convention that is common in browsers and also done when binding events natively. When calling `arc.event_handler.event_row_over();` however, `this` is re-bound to `arc.event_handler` inside `event_row_over`; as it's called as an object method and in such a case `this` points to the object on which the method was called. The method will be called without any arguments.

In the second case you register the function `arc.event_handler.event_row_over` for the event. When called jQuery sets `this` to the related element so inside `event_row_over`, `this` points to that element. `arc.event_handler` is not available in there unless there is some other variable that points to it. jQuery also passes the event object as the first argument so the method is called with that argument.

Usually object methods expect `this` to be their object, so in almost every case you want to use the anonymous function to wrap the call. In case the element matters, pass `this` as an argument to the method.

Another way, without an anonymous function, would be using the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method every function has:

```
$('.event-row').on('mouseover', arc.event_handler.event_row_over.bind(arc.event_handler));
```

However, only modern browsers support this natively.

Comment: thx, ThiefMaster, so in the first case, would adding .call(this) to the end cause this to be bound to .event-row ? I REALLY appreciate answer

Comment: +1. Hurrah for someone explaining `this` without an erroneous reference to [context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10).

Comment: Thx,RobG - but could you give me the one-sentence fleshing out of your comment. Not sure I fully get it.

Comment: think I got it from other comment

Comment: @timpone: It would, but that's usually not what one wants when calling an object's method.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are enclosing the function call in an anonymous function.

In the second case you are just assigning the function pointer..

Comment: ok - what does the anonymous function give me? Sorry for asking dumb question.

Comment: Anonymous function is just a function with no name .. This is used to provide the scope for the variable in this case

Comment: ok, is there a way to explain what it achieves in non-fulltime javascript developer terms. Sorry, every explanation seems really long winded.

Comment: check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures .. Better than me explaining it

Comment: _"This is used to provide the scope for the variable in this case"_ - which variable are you talking about?

Comment: @nnnnnn .. By variable I meant event object

Answer (score 1):

First off, it seems like there is an extra dot in there.. `arc.event_handler.event_row_over.();` should probably be just `arc.event_handler.event_row_over();`

And all the anonymous function does is it calls a member function named `event_row_over` of the `arc.event_handler` object; and it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The 'function' keyword will creates a new closure and encapsulate the scope. Good article on closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures.

Answer (score 1):

The context/scope of the function will not be the same.

Also, with the second one,

```
$('.event-row').on('mouseover',arc.event_handler.event_row_over );
```

you're getting the event object as an argument.

Comment: Yes, for example, 'event_row_over' could be defined as:
`function event_row_over(e) { do_something_with_e; }`

Answer (score 1):

The first case, you have an additional function wrapper. This is useful when you want to do something else before calling the real event handler 'arc.event_handler.event_row_over()' for example you may do something like below:

```
$('.event-row').on('mouseover',function(){
  doPreEventHandling();
  arc.event_handler.event_row_over();
  doPostEventHandling();
});
```

On the other hand you may even extract that annonymous function to be a named function and call as below:

```
var eventHandler = function(){
      doPreEventHandling();
      arc.event_handler.event_row_over();
      doPostEventHandling();
};

$('.event-row').on('mouseover', eventHandler);
```

All above will be just similar in behavior, but more wrapper functions you have more abstraction you gain. But it will compromise performance and sometimes readability.